Auto instrumentation not working for FastAPI service
I am trying to get auto instrumentation working for a FastAPI service, but not having any luck.
By this I mean that the response headers from the FastAPI service don't have the x-b3-spanid and x-b3-traceid response headers.
This is my bootstrap code in main.py
import pkg_resources

from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi import APIRouter
from typing import Dict,Any
from opentelemetry import trace
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from opentelemetry.instrumentation.fastapi import FastAPIInstrumentor
from uvicorn.middleware.proxy_headers import ProxyHeadersMiddleware

import logging
LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)
'''
root_logger = logging.getLogger()
root_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
for handler in root_logger.handlers:
  handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
  
logconfig_dict.update({"root": {"level":"DEBUG", "handlers": ["error"]}})
'''

'''
from opentelemetry import trace, propagators, baggage
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace import TracerProvider
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace.export import (
    BatchSpanProcessor,
    ConsoleSpanExporter,
)

provider = TracerProvider()
processor = BatchSpanProcessor(ConsoleSpanExporter())
provider.add_span_processor(processor)
trace.set_tracer_provider(provider)
'''

tags_metadata = [
    {
        "name": "root",
        "description": "root route",
    }
]

app = FastAPI(
    title="fastapi-otel-test",
    description="This is a REST api that test otel with fastapi.",
    version="0.1.2",
    openapi_tags=tags_metadata,
)
# Freeze OpenAPI verstion. OpenAPI 3.1.0 is not fully backward compatible
app.openapi_version = "3.0.3"
app.add_middleware(ProxyHeadersMiddleware)

'''
def server_request_hook(span, scope: Dict[str, Any]):
     if span and span.is_recording():
         span.set_attribute("service.name", "fastapi-otel")

FastAPIInstrumentor.instrument_app(app,
                                   tracer_provider=provider,
                                   server_request_hook=server_request_hook)
'''
FastAPIInstrumentor.instrument_app(app)

@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    # initialize
    LOG.error("lifespan() start")
    yield
    LOG.info("lifespan() end")

router = APIRouter()

import httpx
@router.get("/", tags=["root"])
async def root():
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
      response = await client.get("http://localhost:8000/foo")
    LOG.info(response.headers)
    return "Hello world"

@router.get("/foo", tags=["root"])
async def foo():
    return "Hello foo"

app.include_router(router)


I run the service as:
./.venv/bin/fastapi dev main.py

Sending a request to the service, even if I provide existing brave span/trace information, does not work. I don't see any response headers.
$ curl -s http://localhost:8000/ -i -H "x-b3-span-id: deadbeef" -H "x-b3-trace-id: baadf00ddeadbeef"
$ HTTP/1.1 200 OK
date: Thu, 10 Oct 2024 22:20:13 GMT
server: uvicorn
content-length: 13
content-type: application/json

"Hello world"

Here is my requirements.txt
fastapi[standard]==0.115.0
httpx
opentelemetry-sdk
opentelemetry-instrumentation-fastapi

I am using python 3.12.
Any idea what I am missing?

I edited the question with a minimal repro
